# Binding ImageSource changeable at DesignTime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**The problem:** 
I would like to create a button template in `XAML` where I bind the image source to a content presenter content box or anything similar.

**Required parameters for the solution:** 
I understand that for a standard button I'm able to add a stackpanel or grid to the button, insert an image into said container and call it a day. However, I'm not a fan of the windows 'chrome' look nor the blue mouse over, click, and focus effects. What I'm attempting to do is create a new button template (editing a copy of the default button template and removing the chrome container) that has the capability to be a base template with the option of changing images as I add more buttons.

Things I've tried and their results:

```
<Button x:Name="btn">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image source="imgsource.png"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

**Result:** Has the button chrome effect. Can be a fall back if nothing else possible but I don't like it.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border x:Name="bContainer" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
                <Grid x:Name="gBody" Background="#FF3C3C3C"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true"/>
                <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true"/>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>    

<Button Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="imgsource.png"/>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

**Result:** The image doesn't show up. I'm thinking this is due to the button custom template, but my knowledge on this is limited so I haven't delved too deep.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border x:Name="bContainer" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
                <Image x:Name="iImage" Source="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="16"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true"/>
                <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true"/>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>    

<Button Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="imgsource.png"/>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

**Result:** The image only shows up when entering the FULL path to the image. I'm not sure if I'm correct, but wouldn't this cause problems when deploying the program?

Comment: Putting a Grid with an Image between `<Button>` and `</Button>` means setting the Content property of the Button. In order to visualize the Content, the ControlTemplate should contain a ContentPresenter.

Comment: Thank you, Clemens!  Jason stated the same idea below.  I have one additional question for that solution that I've posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm kind of surprised your third example works - even with the full path. Just at a glance it does not seem like it should work. Your second attempt is close but you do not have a site to bind the button's content to.

Look at your button:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="imgsource.png"/>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

The `Grid` is the `Content` (the grid is not necessary - you can just put the `Image` there). Looking at your template you can see there is nothing in there that will pick up the content. Try adding a content presenter to your template:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border x:Name="bContainer" 
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" 
                    Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" 
                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" 
                    Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                  Focusable="False"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" 
                         Value="true"/>
                <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" 
                         Value="true"/>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" 
                         Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" 
                            Value="#ADADAD"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Jason, you're absolutely correct and thank you so much for putting it in a way I can understand. I do believe your answer is the correct one, however there's one more step I need when using your solution.  By eliminating the grid from the equation, I no longer have the capability to change the background color which stops me from being able to change the background color for the mouseover and mousedown states.  Is there a way to follow your solution while maintaining that capability?

**EDIT: Ahh! You leave the border in there, which fixes this.  Missed that. This is the correct answer!**

Comment: You do not have to change the background of the button's content from within your templat. In fact, that would probably fall into the 'unexpected behavior' category - user's do not like unexpected behavior. You could change the background of the `Border` inside your template. Edit - I see you already discovered that.